# How to get/approximate distance between 2 close points (given in latitude/longitude)?

Tags: algorithms, trigonometry

I have 2 points with their latitude/longitude coordinates and I know that they are in a X miles radius circle (let's say 10 miles radius) somewhere on earth where it's populated (I mean not near the north pole ;) ). I would like to know if these points are very very close of each other or not. When I say very very close, I mean a few meters (let's say 30 meters).

I don't want to use the heavy formula that returns the exact distance between 2 points anywhere on earth. I'm looking for a simplified formula that would simply answer yes or no to the previous question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The north/south distance is 1 nautical mile per minute of latitude.  The east/west distance is $\cos \phi$ nautical mile per minute of longitude. So you have the total distance in nautical miles is $\sqrt{\Delta \phi^2+\cos^2 \phi \Delta \lambda^2}$ where the distance is in nautical miles and the angles are in minutes.  Alternately, you can express it as $R\sqrt{\Delta \phi^2+\cos^2 \phi \Delta \lambda^2}, R$ the radius of the earth in your favorite units and angles in radians.

Comment: My input is 2 points with their x/y. How do I use your formula with these?

Comment: At the start you said you had latitude and longitude.  $\phi$ is latitude, $\lambda$ longitude.  If you have $x$ and $y$, you can just use $\sqrt{x^2+y^2}$

Comment: So I can see what $\Delta \phi^2$ is but what about $\phi$ alone in the Cos? Which of the 2 points is it?

Comment: If they are as close as you say, the latitudes are very similar.  So use whichever you like, or the average.

Comment: If you want to know if they are within 30 meters$\approx$0.016 n mi, the latitudes will have to be within 0.016 minutes and the longitudes also within 0.016/$\cos \phi$ minutes.

Comment: Not ready in my code to test it yet, but I will surely use your formula. IF there is an issue I'll revisit this page.

Comment: @RossMillikan re "If you want to know if they are within 30 meters.." - to clarify, as you know, that is a first step to quickly discard points that are definitely farther than 30 meters, but since that is testing against a square box, it includes points near the diagonal that are up to 30m in lat + 30m in long or 30 * sqrt(2) ~= 42 miles away. So any points that remain should do the more careful test you show in your answer, or use a more accurate formula.

Comment: Isn't $\Delta \lambda$ supposed to be squared?

Comment: @jman:  Yes.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You could approximate pretty easily by assuming that the surface of the earth is essentially flat within your region.  Then, just use the basic euclidian metric (sticking with your longitude and latitude coordinates).  i.e. if $$\sqrt{(x_1-y_1)^2+(x_2-y_2)^2}<d$$ for whatever distance $d$ then the points are within d of each other.  The only cavet is that you'll require a relatively high degree of precision in your coordinates (though that's obvious if you want to measure distances in meteres).  You'll over estimate a bit, but the error should be small as long as the points are close to each other.

Comment: Given input in lat/long I guess I have a conversion to do to compare to d in meters?

Comment: Yes, but the scaling factor won't be constant as the distance per degree of longitude varies greatly.  You could find the euclidian distance between two local points and compare against that.

Comment: Ultimately though, the formulas to calculate the precise distance (assuming a spherical earth) aren't too complex, what's your resistance to using them?

Comment: So, per your comment, I don't know how to achieve your solution... My resistance is about the number of calculation requests to a web server. Maybe it would be fine but I would prefer to compare the true formula with a simplified one in a benchmark.

Comment: This answer is wrong, if you plug in x and y in lat/long.  Can't do Euclidean formula until you've converted to SOME Euclidean projection. Or at minimum, compensate for the shorter distances in longitude at a given latitude by multiplying each y [longitude] by `cos(lat)`.  And of course there's a typo in your formula - you must mean `Sqrt( (x2-x1) squared + (y2-y1) squared )` - the formula you show has no meaning. Bottom line: getting this approach "correct" requires a lot of careful testing of various values vs some accurate formula, until all results are acceptable.

Comment: @ToolmakerSteve - I am not a hardcore math guy, but your comment makes the most sense of any. I'm building an app which must be accurate for shorter distances, within 50 miles, and only very vaguely accurate as it get's further away. Could you possibly complete your answer with a viable formula for this?

Comment: Is this what you are suggesting: 
Sqrt( (x2-x1) squared + ((y2 * cos(x2))  - (y1 * cos(x1)) squared )

Comment: First, Ross Millikan's answer is more precise. Here, its best to multiply both y's by the same latitude (otherwise have to subtract a compensating term, that I don't know off the top of my head). I multiply by the average of the two latitudes. For short distances, this is "good enough":  `avgCosLat = (cos(x1) + cos(x2)) / 2;` `Sqrt( (x2-x1) squared + (avgCosLat * (y2 - y1)) squared);`  Note that `avgCosLat` is part of what gets "squared". Whatever formula you use, compare the result to some "exact" distance formula, for different inputs. To be sure this is "good enough" for your purpose.

Answer (score 0):

Searching for an algorithm to easily compute distances I came across this question, and Ross Millikan answer looked exactly like what I needed.

However everybody agreed that this was to be used for short distances, but... how much short?

So I compared the result of Ross formula with the great-circle distance usually used to compute distances. I used [TinyGps++](https://github.com/mikalhart/TinyGPSPlus/blob/master/src/TinyGPS%2B%2B.cpp#L285) algorithm for the great circle. What I discovered is that the error between the two formulas is maximised when going at 45° (i.e. moving 1m north and 1m west), rather than going straight north or west.

Then both algorithms do not care about the absolute value of the longitude, but only use the difference between the two values. However latitude is used in an absolute way.

So I tried to plot the difference between the algorithms outputs. The approximate one (i.e. Ross's one) always overestimates the real distance.

Here is a graph showing how much the approximate algorithm overestimates the distance. I plotted lines for distances of 100m, 1km, 10km, 100km, 1000km and 10000km, going at a 45° direction (so for instance going 70.7m north and 70.7m east), at different latitudes

[image: Comparison between algorithms]

As you can see, the error grows larger as we get to the poles. Restricting the "useful" range to +/- 75°, the max error of this algorithm is about 1mm for a 100m movement (0.001%), raising to 10cm for a 1km movement (0.01%), 10m for 10km (0.1%), 1km for 100km (1%). AT 50°N/S this error drops by 66% (i.e. 0.33mm for 100m).

Then I tried to use the average value for the latitudes in the cosine in Ross's algorithm instead of one of the two values. And this is the associated graph

[image: Comparison between algorithms - average latitude]

(I left the same scale for easier comparison)

The error dropped dramatically; at +/-75° the error is 14nm @ 100m, 14um @ 1km, 14mm @ 10km,  14m @ 100km.

This suggests that the approximate algorithm can be used up to several kilometers, while when there is a need for larger distances the approximate algorithm that takes into account the average latitude has a very large precision. When going too close to the poles, however, the error becomes larger and larger, so penguins won't be able to take advantage of this

Feel free to correct me; it's 1AM to the probability of me having messed up some calculations is non-negligible ;)

Comment: My approximations, like many, assume the problem is linear.  In particular my distance formula approximates the sphere of the earth as a Euclidean plane.  That is reasonably accurate over small distances, where the value of small is larger near the equator than the poles.  When you talk of tens of meters, as OP did, you can get rather close to the poles and still have an acceptable error.  For careful work you should state bounds on where the error is acceptable, based on a stated acceptable error